# How do I organize my REST API codes along with the codes for generating the website?

Tags: web-development, rest, clean-code, deployment, code-organization

Using github as an example, `www.github.com` is the website people visit and `api.github.com` is the REST api server programs will visit. But they probably share some codebase and in my case they share a lot.

We actually developed the rest server first for our mobile apps then we decided to develop a website because we had though there were quite some codes can be reused (same programming language of course). But now codes are not clean at all and I am trying to refactor them.

The similarity between them and the problems I need to fix include:

First, the logic to access the database is basically the same. After get the data, the REST codes will just return them as JSON while the "website code" (without a better word to describe them) will feed the data to the template which then generates the html pages.

Second, the router logics share in common a lot.

Third, I need to make the deployment easy. We use nginx to direct REST request to the rest server and website request (again, without a better word) to the website server, which is different from the rest server(2 standalone servers).

So how do I organize the source codes to be DRY & be easy deployment ?

--- update ---

If you down voted or close voted can you please leave some comments why ? To me this is a legitimate question and I have been doing refactoring for a while. Thank!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're not going the route of having the website use the rest-api (it's a typical approach for [SPA web frameworks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) like [Angular](https://angular.io/) or [React](https://reactjs.org/)), then you can move the logic into a common "Service Layer" code base that (assuming the web framework and rest api use the same languages) can be shared between them.

Let's take a simple example. If you have an API endpoint to create a task on a todo list. It's job is to verify and process the inbound data, connect to the database and create the appropriate entry. And you have a function backing your website that does the exact same work. You can pull that functionality into a TaskService object in a separate library that does the exact same operation. You reference that library in both the REST API and in the Web Application and delegate the operation to the TaskService.

Answer (score 1):

There are two major ways of keeping your codebase DRY:

- Create your web-application as a Single Page Application (SPA): The webserver just gives out a web-application written in JavaScript that runs entirely in the browser. This web-application makes requests to the REST API to retrieve data and/or make changes.
- Leverage the strength of the Model-View-Controller (MVC) design pattern: In the MVC pattern, the Controller receives the web requests and does as little as possible to determine which Model functions to call and which View to return. The View transforms the data retrieved from the Model into the expected response format (e.g. JSON or HTML). The Model contains the business logic and the storage of the data, but it doesn't know how the application communicates with its users.

  If you do this right, the Model can be reused without change in a REST API, a web-application (serving HTML pages) or even in a desktop application. Thus you can create one Model that is shared, a set of Controllers and Views for the REST API and a similar set for the website.

Comment: A. We don't want our website to SPA for couple of reasons. B. I believe everyone is doing MVC, how well you are doing it is another story.